# How two combine two columns of different dataframes such that they have unique values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different dataframes and I want to get the sorted
values of two columns.

**Setup**

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': range(7),
    'c': list('EDBBCCC')
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': range(8),
    'c': list('EBBCCCAA')
    })
```

**Desired Output**

```
# notice that ABCDE appear in alphabetical order
c_first c_second
NAN A
B   B
C   C
D   NAN
E   E
```

**What I've tried**

```py
pd.concat([df1.c.sort_values().drop_duplicates().rename('c_first'),
           df2.c.sort_values().drop_duplicates().rename('c_second')
           ],axis=1)
```

How to get the output as given in required format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here one possible way to achive it:

```
t1 = df1.c.drop_duplicates()
t2 = df2.c.drop_duplicates()

tmp1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':t1, 'c_first':t1})
tmp2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':t2, 'c_second':t2})

result = pd.merge(tmp1,tmp2, how='outer').sort_values('id').drop('id', axis=1)
result
   c_first c_second
4     NaN        A
0       B        B
1       C        C
2       D      NaN
3       E        E
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

There is an argument in concat function. 
Try to add `sort=True`.